# Disable An item in a gridview, store app

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-store-apps

I have a gridview in a store app which is dynamically bound to a Collection

```
<GridView x:Name="Gridview1" Height="180"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
       ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" SelectionMode="None"   >
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <Border  Background="White" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="3" Height="150" Width="150" Tapped="peopleDashboard_Tapped" PointerEntered="Gridview1_PointerEntered" PointerExited="Gridview1_PointerExited"  >

                <Grid Margin="5"   >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TileName}"   FontSize="18" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"

                         TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TileValue}" Foreground="Orange" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                         TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>

            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>

</GridView>
```

And I am binding this gridview in code behind like this

```
Gridview1.ItemsSource = listObj;
```

I will get 7 boxes . on hover gridview has a hover border color for each item.
I need to disable just one particular item in the gridview.
I can write `Gridview1.IsEnabled = false` for disabling the whole gridview.

But I need to disable only a particular item.

Here is a picture of the populated gridview 
[image: Here is a picture of the populated gridview]

[image: This is the disabled gridview]

this is the disabled gridview.

I need to disable only one box in the gridview.
 Any possible suggestions ?

Comment: You could add a boolean Property "IsEnabled" to your listObj and then use databinding to bind this to the isEnabled property of your grid (not the whole gridview)

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: That will not work. data is bound to the whole gridview. It will not set the "IsEnabled". Items in DataTemplate are border and grid which does not have "IsEnabled" property.

Comment: I have tried another way around, by using pointer entered and pointer exit events, set the pointer cursor as red non clickable universal No.
 Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = new Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursor(Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursorType.UniversalNo, 1);
But this is not really the thing that I want.

Comment: Why use Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor ... Just extract DataTemplate from <GridView.ItemTemplate> to UserControl. In this UserControl hook on PointerEvents like PointerEntered, PointerExited etc. and implement visual of your control e.g. blue border on PointerEntered

Answer (score 0):

you can try it with IValue Converter. When binding the data if Value is 'InProgress' make it disable, something like this you want I think. Try googling how to use IValue Converter.

Answer (score 0):

many years later....I stumbled upon this problem myself when trying to make some inactive items in my UWP project..my solution was to employ use of the extended DataTemplateSelector that allows one to enable/disable the gridview item based on the associated class object's properties as described here:

https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/disable-item-selection-winrt-gridview/

```
<Page.Resouces>

        <DataTemplate x:Name "ActiveItem" >
            <Border  Background="White" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="3" Height="150" Width="150" Tapped="peopleDashboard_Tapped" PointerEntered="Gridview1_PointerEntered" PointerExited="Gridview1_PointerExited"  >

                <Grid Margin="5"   >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TileName}"   FontSize="18" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"

                         TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TileValue}" Foreground="Orange" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                         TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>

            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Name "InactiveItem"  >
            <Border  Background="White" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="3" Height="150" Width="150" Tapped="peopleDashboard_Tapped" PointerEntered="Gridview1_PointerEntered" PointerExited="Gridview1_PointerExited"  >

                <Grid Margin="5"   >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TileName}"   FontSize="18" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"

                         TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TileValue}" Foreground="Orange" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                         TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>

            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>

        <local:SelectionItemTemplateSelector x:Key="DataTemplateSelector" ActiveItemDataTemplate="{StaticResource ActiveItem}" InactiveItemTemplate="{StaticResource InactiveItem}"/>


</Page.Resources>


<GridView x:Name="Gridview1" Height="180"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
       ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" SelectionMode="None" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource DataTemplateSelector}"  >

</GridView>
```